# Segmentation fault and dereferencing pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dereference

I'm working on a project for school and I have to implement a queue.
I wrote some very simple tests in my main.c file to see if everything worked fine, but I get two errors I don't know how to fix, and I might need a little help from you guys !

### First error

The first error I get is a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I know it has to do with a memory access problem, but honestly I don't know what I did wrong. Is there a simple way to debug segfaults in c ?

### Second error

By the way, when I uncomment line 9 of my main.c

```
printf("One node added, size = %d\n",my_queue->size);
```

I get another error message:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:47: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘queue_t’ {aka ‘struct queue’}
    9 |  printf("One node added, size = %d\n",my_queue->size);
      |                                               ^~
```

I found out that this error occurs when you try to dereference a struct that hasn't been defined (or declared) yet. This message surprises me because I did declare my type queue_t in my header file queue.h and I did define it in my queue.c file.

You can find all the files i'm talking about on this [repo](https://forge.uclouvain.be/dhoutart/project_test)

Thanks a lot for your help and have a good day !

Diego

Comment: Maybe post the code you knwo is making the error? Also, the idea of this site is to be usefull, so please paste the code where the error is, so everyone can see. Maybe it will be helpfull to someone else. If you just throw a site where you have it and you modify it over some time, nobody will see what caused the error.

Comment: Please include the code in the question. Do not include external links. Please create a [MCVE]. `because I did declare my type queue_t`  Yes, but you did not _define_ queue_t. Thus the error - the type if not defined and the type is incomplete. `Is there a simple way to debug segfaults in c?` [Search the google on how to debug C programs](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+debug+C+program).

Comment: The best way to debug the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` for me is to `valgrind`.

Comment: If you're getting a core dump, that's useful.  Assuming your core dump file is named "core" (often it will be `core.pid`, but it can be easily configured and may be anything), run `gdb $exe core` (where $exe is the path to your executable).

Comment: one more thing i see in your source code. I don't understand why do you have to define 2 times type of `queue_t` (one in queue.h and another in queue.c) ?

Comment: @Hitokiri That's how header files work...

Comment: Since the full declaration of `queue_t` has been hidden from main.c inside queue.c, why not define a function to return the length of a queue?

Comment: @Aplet123 why doesn't he move `typedef struct {} queue_t` in `queue.c` to `queue.h`. it's enough, no ?

Comment: @Hitokiri Using an incomplete type (opaque type) in a header file is a way to hide the implementation details (the members of the structure) from the API. This way the implementation can be changed without changing and without even recompiling the calling functions that use the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation error `dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘queue_t’` results from dereferencing a pointer to `queue_t` in `main` which is an incomplete type AKA opaque type.

The API in `queue.h` is designed to hide the definition of the structure `queue_t` from the caller. The calling functions are supposed to use a pointer to this structure only. So the caller is not supposed to know that there is a structure field `size`.

The clean way to solve this would be to add a getter function to the API to return the requested value. The function should be declared in `queue.h` and implemented in `queue.c`, e.g.

```
int get_size(queue_t *queue)
{
    int size = -1; /* error return value */
    if(queue != NULL)
    {
        size = queue->size;
    }
    return size;
}
```

(As a hack you could add a copy of the structure definition to `main.c`. **I don't recommend this.**)

---

To check the segmentation fault I compiled the program with

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.c queue.c -o main
```

Running the program with `valgrind` as

```
valgrind ./main
```

I get several error messages

```
==25539== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25539== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25539== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25539== Command: ./main
==25539== 
First node added had value 42
==25539== Invalid read of size 4
==25539==    at 0x1092FC: dequeue (queue.c:45)
==25539==    by 0x109200: main (main.c:14)
==25539==  Address 0x4a5a0e8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==25539==    at 0x483BA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25539==    by 0x1093AE: dequeue (queue.c:60)
==25539==    by 0x1091E1: main (main.c:13)
==25539==  Block was alloc'd at
==25539==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25539==    by 0x10926D: enqueue (queue.c:25)
==25539==    by 0x1091C4: main (main.c:10)
==25539== 
==25539== Invalid read of size 8
==25539==    at 0x109359: dequeue (queue.c:54)
==25539==    by 0x109200: main (main.c:14)
==25539==  Address 0x4a5a0e0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==25539==    at 0x483BA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25539==    by 0x1093AE: dequeue (queue.c:60)
==25539==    by 0x1091E1: main (main.c:13)
==25539==  Block was alloc'd at
==25539==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25539==    by 0x10926D: enqueue (queue.c:25)
==25539==    by 0x1091C4: main (main.c:10)
==25539== 
==25539== Invalid read of size 8
==25539==    at 0x109382: dequeue (queue.c:57)
==25539==    by 0x109200: main (main.c:14)
==25539==  Address 0x4a5a0e0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==25539==    at 0x483BA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25539==    by 0x1093AE: dequeue (queue.c:60)
==25539==    by 0x1091E1: main (main.c:13)
==25539==  Block was alloc'd at
==25539==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25539==    by 0x10926D: enqueue (queue.c:25)
==25539==    by 0x1091C4: main (main.c:10)
==25539== 
==25539== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==25539==    at 0x483BA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25539==    by 0x1093A2: dequeue (queue.c:59)
==25539==    by 0x109200: main (main.c:14)
==25539==  Address 0x4a5a0e0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==25539==    at 0x483BA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25539==    by 0x1093AE: dequeue (queue.c:60)
==25539==    by 0x1091E1: main (main.c:13)
==25539==  Block was alloc'd at
==25539==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25539==    by 0x10926D: enqueue (queue.c:25)
==25539==    by 0x1091C4: main (main.c:10)
==25539== 
Second node added had value 43
==25539== 
==25539== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25539==     in use at exit: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==25539==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 1,088 bytes allocated
==25539== 
==25539== LEAK SUMMARY:
==25539==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==25539==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25539==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25539==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25539==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25539== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==25539== 
==25539== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==25539== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Apparently you have already `free`d a node in function `dequeue` at line 60

```
            free(cur);
```

and you access this node at line 45

```
        int tbr = q->tail->value; //value to be returned
```

and line 54

```
                cur = cur->next;
```

and line 57

```
            cur->next = old->next;
```

Then at line 59 you try to `free` this block again

```
            free(old);
```

By adding debug `printf`s at the entry and return of `enqueue` and `dequeue` I found out that the first call to `dequeue` doesn't result in an error and returns in the `else` branch.
The errors occur in the second call to `dequeue` which also returns in the `else` branch.
Apparently in the first call to `dequeue` you `free` a node that will be used and `free`d in the second call.

I didn't analyze your program in detail, but I guess that it is wrong to `free` both `old` and `cur` in `dequeue`.

Run your program step by step using a debugger and think about how the nodes of your list are connected and when you have to `free` which node.